# concatenating profile messages in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, concatenation, spring-profiles

So I want to concatenate two messages from profile in spring boot.
This is my current code (Which is not working because fields are null):

```
@Profile("fetchGame")
@Service
public class FetchGameApiService {

@Value("${game.api.url}")
private static String LINK;

@Value("${game.api.key}")
private static String KEY;

private static Integer gameId = 1;

private static final String URL = LINK + "/" + gameId + "?key=" + KEY;

//somelogic
}
```

Here is my profile page:

```
game.api.url = https://api.rawg.io/api/games
game.api.key = 250b2de5e7734f638760ae2bad8bd29f
this_IS_The_Correct_Url = https://api.rawg.io/api/games/1?key=250b2de5e7734f638760ae2bad8bd29f
```

Note That I have set active profile in app.properties as: spring.profiles.active = fetchGame
My Question is: How is the proper way to concatenate two strings into one from spring profiles? Without having a huge amount of code and make it simple and understandable.

Comment: `@Value("${game.api.url}") private static String KEY; ` should that be `@Value("${game.api.key}") private static String KEY;`? Aside from that, you cannot inject `static` fields.

Comment: oh ur right i will fix it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, spring profile has nothing to do w/ injecting values to fields or method/constructor arguments.
[Spring profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles) allow configuring application context conditionally.

Here is the list to check out:

- Make sure to keep fields non-static.
- Check if `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean is registered in context
- Or use `@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")` to set a custom property file to resolve values from.

Here is the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-value-annotations) on the feature.

I suggest learning and adopting type safe way to deal w/ [configuration properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.java-bean-binding) w/ `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation.